# Forward stdout bytes from Process to WebSocket or read current InputStream length

Tags: java, websocket, ffmpeg, inputstream, processbuilder

I'm using [Jaffree](https://github.com/kokorin/Jaffree) library to convert and display my RTSP stream using FFmpeg.

I'm doing exactly the same thing as [node-rtsp-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rtsp-stream) library, but in **Java** instead of Node.js

1. Run ffmpeg with proper arguments and stdOut.
2. Catch packets / bytes emitted by stdOut.
3. Send them to client using WebSocket.

I'm using [JSMpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg) on the client side to display the stream - case is exactly the same as in node-rtsp-stream.

Everything is working fine, but I have problems with memory optimization and consumption.

Piece of code from Jaffree library that handles the process:

```
protected Executor startExecution(final Process process,
                                  final AtomicReference<T> resultReference) {
    Executor executor = new Executor(contextName);

    if (stdOutReader != null) {
        executor.execute("StdOut", new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                T result = stdOutReader.read(process.getInputStream());
                if (result != null) {
                    boolean set = resultReference.compareAndSet(null, result);
                    if (!set) {
                        LOGGER.warn("Ignored result of reading STD OUT: {}", result);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My StdOutReader implementation:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048000;

@Override
public T read(final InputStream stream) {
  Try.run(() -> {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int length;

    while ((length = stream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
      final byte[] finalBuffer = new byte[length];
      System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, finalBuffer, 0, length);
      socket.sendMessage(finalBuffer);
    }
  }).onFailure(throwable -> {
    throw new RuntimeException("FFmpeg error", throwable);
  });

  return null;
}
```

Under the hood there is a simple `Process` that returns `InputStream` (actually `BufferedInputStream`, which is very important).

My problem is that I don't know how many bytes there is in the stream and `JSMpeg` needs specific number (frame / packet) to display stream properly without any disturbance.
So I've created artificially huge byte array to handle the biggest results, but my memory suffers from that.

I want to just forward every of this packet using WebSocket. So it should work like this (and it works this way now):

`StdOut sends packet -> passing packet to WebSocket -> StdOut sends packet -> passing packet to WebSocket -> ...`

Another option is to somehow predict the number of bytes that `InputStream` holds at this moment, but this is probably not possible with `BufferedInputStream`.

1. I've tried reading string lines with `Reader` and converting them to bytes, but they return wrong sizes - that does not work.
2. I've tried setting some buffer / length size of packets on ffmpeg - that does not work or stream gets broken.
3. I've noticed that these packets are multiplications of 188 bytes, but even converting packets to similar size make stream broken (they probably need to have size taken directly from stdOut).
4. I've tried `readAllBytes()` but then loop ends.
5. I've tried some things with `transferTo` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` - nothing helped.
6. I've tried checking `available()` size of `InputStream`, but that does not work either.
7. I've tried using Spring 5 WebFlux `DataBuffer` by converting `Stream` to `Flux` and subscribing, but there I can only read single bytes (or maybe I don't know how to read whole current buffer).

Maybe it is somewhat possible to modify JSMpeg to receive static-size packets (I mean always 2048 bytes for example) - if so, let me know.

Or maybe I can somehow predict length of a packet from specific byte that was sent to stdOut - if so, let me know.

How can I achieve that and is it even possible?

** First edition **

I've implemented it using `PipeOutput` according to Denis Kokorin answer, but it has the exact same limitations. Under the hood `PipeOutput` just copies stream content to `new byte[]` initialized with predefined buffer size. So i get output like this:

```
Array length: 262144, actual length: 9588
Array length: 262144, actual length: 4700
Array length: 262144, actual length: 9024
Array length: 262144, actual length: 10152
Array length: 262144, actual length: 18048
```

I need to send arrays with actual length (using WebSocket) rather than array length. The reason is the way that [JSMpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg) library works:

> The internal buffers for video and audio are fairly small (512kb and
> 128kb respectively) and JSMpeg **will discard old (even unplayed) data**
> to make room for newly arriving data without much fuzz. This could
> introduce decoding artifacts when there's a network congestion, but
> ensures that latency is kept at a minimum.

Default buffer size of JSMpeg is `524 288` and that way nothing gets displayed.

I'm pretty sure that with `ChannelOutput` the thing will be pretty similar. If not, give me a hint on how to pass data from `SeekableByteChannel` using WebSocket.

> You mentioned Spring and probably you use it for WebSockets too.
> Spring uses STOMP protocol over WebSockets. WebSockets are almost like
> TCP Sockets: they allow you to send arbitrary bytes. STOMP is similar
> to HTTP. So it's possible to stream bytes over WebSocket, but without
> STOMP.

Yes, I have not mentioned it directly. I'm using Spring 5 indeed with `spring-boot-starter-websocket` package. In my specific case I need to use STOMP, but I send those bytes using normal Java function - I pass `byte[]` as a parameter (`SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend`).

> I also would like to suggest an alternative solution: if something
> doesn't fit in memory - save it on disk.

It's probably not and option for me. It is a live stream, not a standard video and I have to keep latency as low as possible.

> Encode MJPEG right after file upload.

It is not MJPEG format - it is `mpegts`. JSMpeg is a name of the library. :)

The ffmpeg command looks like that:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel level+info -i rtsp://test:test@10.10.10.10:554/stream -n -rtsp_transport tcp -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -r 30 -s 480x320 -b:v 1500k -bf 0 -an -vf scale=480:320 -
```

Comment: Check PipeOutput.pumpTo(final OutputStream destination, final int bufferSize). You can configure buffer size.

Comment: @DenisKokorin The problem is that `bufferSize` is a static value. I don't know if a packet length will be 9588, 18048, 108288 or 4700. I want to somehow predict / extract the length of specific packet. If I initialize `bufferSize` as 20000 for example, the rest of the bytes will be sent as zeros, which will also break streaming.

Comment: OutputStream has method writeBytes(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length). You can use Arrays.copy() to fill byte array of size length.

Comment: Exactly, but note that this is exactly what I do in the code above in `StdOutReader` implementation (`read` method). I need to create one huge buffer size and then for every iteration (couple milliseconds) create another array - over and over again. I am looking for a way to pass amount of bytes from packet directly to websocket, or if it is not possible, pull (using stream `read` method) a specific packet size from `InputStream`. Is it possible?

Comment: But why do you need huge buffer? Put it to be 200_000 and in OutputStream#write copy all available bytes to new byte array and send to web socket.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of Jaffree.

First of all, you need no custom `StdReader`, you can use `PipeOutput`:

```java
var outputStream = new OutputStreamWebSocketWrapper(...);

FFmpeg.atPath()
  .addInput(urlInput.fromUrl("path/to/file.mp4"))
  .addOutput(
      PipeOutput.pumpTo(outputStream)
        .setFormat("flv")
  )
  .execute();
```

`OutputStreamWebSocketWrapper` above should be simple `OutputStream` implementation which sends bytes to WebSocket.

> My problem is that I don't know how many bytes there is in the stream and JSMpeg needs specific number (frame / packet) to display stream properly without any disturbance. So I've created artificially huge byte array to handle the biggest results, but my memory suffers from that.

It looks like you have a problem with HTTP Server and `OutputStream`. Some servers (almost all that I know) by default first read **all** data from `OutputStream` and only after that start sending data to a client. And they do so because of `content-length` header. But it's possible to instruct some servers to stream data in real. In that case a client gets no `content-length` (unless you specify the value yourself) and hence doesn't know how much data left.

You mentioned Spring and probably you use it for WebSockets too. Spring uses STOMP protocol over WebSockets. WebSockets are almost like TCP Sockets: they allow you to send arbitrary bytes. STOMP is similar to HTTP. So it's possible to stream bytes over WebSocket, but without STOMP.

I also would like to suggest an alternative solution: if something doesn't fit in memory - save it on disk. You didn't say it explicitly, but I suspect that you try to implement on-the-fly conversion of a video file to MJPEG stream and to send it to a client. This conversion is CPU intensive anyway and can cause problems with high number of concurrent connections. Also with in-memory on-the-fly you can't reuse data converted earlier. Also WebSockets can't be cached as simple as HTTP responses can.

So instead you could go with one of the 2 following ways:

1. Encode by request (but once): check if MJPEG is already created, if not create it and serve it
2. Encode MJPEG right after file upload. Serve MJPEG as common files

** UPDATE **

After discussion in comments I suggest the following snippet:

```java
OutputStream websocketOutput = new OutputStream() {            
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // not implemented
    }
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, offset, data, 0, length);
        socket.sendMessage(data);
    }
};
FFmpeg.atPath()
        .addInput(UrlInput.fromUrl("rtsp://servername/streamname"))
        .addOutput(
                PipeOutput.pumpTo(websocketOutput, 200_000)
                        .setFormat("mpegts")
                        .setCodec(StreamType.VIDEO, "mpeg1video")
                // other arguments here
        )
        .execute();
```

So you don't need huge buffer, just pass to WebSocket every iteration all meaningful bytes you got.

Comment: `PipeOutput` unfortunately does not work as intended. I've edited the question and provided some more clarification and explanation. Let me know if there is a way to achieve what I want. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: I have added code snippet